# asp:button Return behaviour

Tags: c#, asp.net, button

I have a bunch of buttons on my page and beside a textbox I have a Search button.

Now when I hit the return key on the keyboard it actually activates the Add user button which is right above.

How to link the textbox with the search button?

Comment: You can use javascript/jquery to read the keycode, compare it to "13" which is for return/enter key and set the focus to the search button.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the default button for your form:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" defaultbutton="btn1">
```

You can use asp:panel for setting default button.

```
<form runat="server">
<asp:Panel runat="server" DefaultButton="bt1">

<asp:TextBox runat="server" />
<asp:Button id="bt1" Text="Default" runat="server" />

</asp:Panel>
</form>
```

Comment: That works perfectly since I just have one button with an input. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Following javascript method will do it for you:

```
function clickButton(e, buttonid){
  var evt = e ? e : window.event;
  var bt = document.getElementById(buttonid);
  if (bt){
      if (evt.keyCode == 13){
            bt.click();
            return false;
      }
  }
}
```

In code behind, attach this event with your textbox like:

```
TextBox1.Attributes.Add("onkeypress", "return clickButton(event,'" + Button1.ClientID + "')");
```